# what is the best way of using class dynamically

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, user-controls

**UPDATE: I completely reformulated the question**

I am trying to implement an algorithm that would change the class name dynamically.
For Example:

Data.cs

```
public class Data
{

    public string text1 { get; set; }
    public string text2 { get; set; }

}
```

User1.ascx

```
public partial class User1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public Data datas = new Data();
}
```

User2.ascx

```
public partial class User2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public Data datas = new Data();
}
```

User.aspx

```
public partial class User: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    [WebMethod]
    public static string RequestUC(Data datas) 
    {
    if (datas.userfile = "User1.ascx")
    {
         User1 userControl = (User1)page.LoadControl(datas.userfile);
    }
    else
    {
         User2 userControl = (User2)page.LoadControl(datas.userfile);
    }

    using (Page page = new Page())
            {                               
                userControl.datas = datas;  // the error says that the  userControl not recognized
                page.Controls.Add(userControl);
                using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
                {
                    page.Controls.Add(userControl);
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
                    return writer.ToString();
                }
            }
    }

    }
```

The problem is I can't get the User.aspx work. Any solutions would work.

How can I use generics in this case?

thank YOU

Comment: What do you mean by "load more than one ascx dynamically"?  Are you asking how you can have a generic method for loading user controls that nonetheless lets you access properties specific to that user control?

Comment: Sorry, I meant one ascx but dynamically

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: the problem is I cant map data object from UserConroller class, I can do that only by accessing the myusercontrol class. is it possible to bind data object to the contro UserConroller class object

Comment: Could you reformulate the question? What's the real problem? Why you can't access data? userControl = (MyuserControl )page.LoadControl(con); could do the job!

Comment: @Fals yeah but the next line isn't. I can't use usercontrol.datas this time.that is actuqlly what I need

Comment: @Fals I made it a little clearer

Comment: it won't work on an webmethod, only on a postback...

Comment: @nozari actually it works if I use just user1 or user2 alone. But I want to use them interchangly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inheritance.

Create a base user control class:

```
public abstract class UserControlBase : System.Web.UI.UserControl {
    public abstract Data Datas { get; set; }
}
```

Then derive each user control from that class (and implement the abstract properties, not shown):

```
public partial class User1 : UserControlBase

public partial class User2 : UserControlBase
```

And in your web method:

```
//TODO - validate that datas.userfile is appropriate
UserControlBase myControl = page.LoadControl(datas.userfile);
```

Comment: Thanks Jason P, let me try

Comment: You don't need to cast to `User1` or `User2`, just cast to `UserControlBase` and get rid of the `if` block.

Comment: Guys thanks, but there is small error here :'User1' does not implement inherited abstract member 'UserControlBase.datas.get'  and set as well, please help. I am hopping that it's gonna work,please please please

Comment: Yep, that was my note about implementing the abstract properties. You should be able to right click the class name and find "implement abstract class" or something similar in the context menu. However, I would read up on inheritance, abstract classes, and polymorphism, which are OOP basics.

Comment: I am sorry, How should I change public override Data Datas {get{throw new NotImplementedException();} set{ throw new NotImplementedException();}}. Now the method gives me an error. In my particalar case. Thank You

Comment: How do I add text1 and text2 to my implementation

Comment: Can't solve it still, how do I suppose to search, My Data class is a POCO class, which has varilable text1 and text2. But it's asks me to implement the datas, not touching the text1 and text2, Iam a little confused. Please help me how can I search?

Comment: Remove the NotImplementedException part and just do { get; set; } for auto-implemented properties

Comment: @Jason P Ohhh my god, my ears suddenly became red. Thank you Jason P you saved me. I have read a lot about programming, but when it come's to implementation it sucks. maybe stupidity or lack experience, thank you very much,

Comment: @Jason P by your help I now have a more sense about implementations, abstracts, and other staff.(this is the first time I am using them in real world), and I really wanna cry. I have been reading a billion times about plymorphisim,delegates, but it still doesn't fulfill me. Appreciate